# Selenium - xpath has stopped finding the elements

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Hi I have a big problem,

I have been creating an automated script and been testing it as I have been building.
I have made it to line 109 and now line 64 has started failing.

This line has been working many many times before and has stopped suddenly without any real information to help resolve.

Here is the code that I am using the xpath to extract the element from

```
<div id="content_category_4c42556772376a443736343d_cars" class="category-content" style="display: block;">
<div id="item_4a7366327a7877496d68303d" class="item">
<div id="item_484a3250456b6e754464733d" class="item">
<div id="item_422f585379587a766749553d" class="item">
</div>
```

I am using the following code using xpath to select the first item in the list

```
String carsinAuction = selenium.getValue("//*[@class='item'][1]");
```

This line has been working fine all day and now it fails every time I execute the script. I now get an error that the element is not found.

When I navigate to the page and use firepath entering the same xpath the element is found.

Does anybody have any idea why this would stop working all of a sudden, has this happened to anybody before?

I have attempted to search forums for an answer but I cannot thing of a search term that brings back meaningful results to my problem.

Thanks in advance

Tony

Comment: `selenium.getValue()`?!?! What is `selenium` in your code?

Comment: try (//*[@class='item'])[1] ..

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that now why it is not working while previously it was working. But if your id is unique why are using `class='item'`

Please try please xpath:-

```
//div[@id='item_4a7366327a7877496d68303d']
```

OR More specific

```
//div[@id='content_category_4c42556772376a443736343d_cars']/div[@id='item_4a7366327a7877496d68303d']
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: HI, I can't use the hardcoded ID because the item ID is unique to an item and the item will not be in the next auction, the easiest way of scripting it so that it will not need heavy maintainance is to use the class='item'

Comment: can you please share the link where you are facing this issue?

Comment: Would you mind if I sent this privately please, I am not sure I can share this publically

Comment: If the link requires login etc then yes you should not post here. you can share more HTML code here